# SwiftyJson Results in UITableView wrong order

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swifty-json

I'm working on a simple JSON reader app using Alamofire and SwiftyJson. Getting the file and parsing them into the UITableView is working fine except for the fact that it shows them in the wrong results.

How do I get them to show in the order as specified by the JSON file?

Here is the output:
[image]

As you can see, Category3 shows first, then Category1.

I would like them in the order of the Json:

```
{"Posts": [
{
    "Category1": [
        "Post1",
        "Post2",
        "Post3",
        "Post4",
        "Post5",
        "Post6",
        "Post7"
    ],
    "Category2": [
        "Post1",
        "Post2",
        "Post3",
        "Post4",
        "Post5",
        "Post6",
        "Post7",
        "Post8"
    ],
    "Category3": [
        "Post1",
        "Post2"
    ]
}
]}
```

View Controller code:

```
func getSectionsFromData(completion: ([Sections]) -> ()) {
    var sectionsArray = [Sections]()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)

                for (_, subJson) in json["Posts"] {
                    for (title, data) in subJson {
                        let optionalCastedObjects = data.arrayObject as? [String]
                        let unwrappedObjects = optionalCastedObjects ?? []
                        let section = Sections(title: title, objects: unwrappedObjects)

                        sectionsArray.append(section)
                    }
                }

                completion(sectionsArray)
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

UITableView Reload:

```
SectionsData().getSectionsFromData { [weak self](sections: [Sections]) -> () in
        self?.sections = sections
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
        self!.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're populating an array from looping over a dictionary:

```
for (title, data) in subJson
```

*(`subJson` is the dictionary with the categories)*

Swift Dictionaries are unordered collections, so your array is populated "out of order".

This is working as expected. ;)

If you can't change the JSON at the source, then just `sort()` your array once it's populated - but it would be better to change the categories storing strategy and not make it dependent on dictionary keys order.

To sort your array, you could do something like that:

```
let sectionsArraySorted = sectionsArray.sort { $0.title < $1.title }
completion(sectionsArraySorted)
```

But it definitely would be better to change the JSON structure, the current one is not ideal for this task.

Comment: This gives me this error: Value of Type 'sections' has no member 'title' :/

Comment: ignore that, The title gets changed to headings in the struct, using headings worked. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful, in Swift 3, the non-mutating `sort` has become `sorted` again, and the mutating one is `sort`.